# why I can't use request.query.limit in firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

from video tutorial in here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sOT5VOflvQ

it is said that I can limit my query limit. but it seems the query properties is not available in request object

[image]

as you can see, it is not available in drop down, and if I use the code below, the access will be denied

```
match /cities/{cityID} {
      allow list: if isSignedIn() && request.query.limit <= 20; 
    }
```

Comment: Don't trust the options in that box.  It doesn't have a full understanding of the security rules language.  Go ahead and use it exactly as you see in the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query). Please edit the question to show the **entire** set of rules, as well as the specific query code that isn't working the way you expect with the rules you're showing - rules don't have meaning without a query that should work with them.  We should be able to reproduce the problem using the information in the question.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, any progress??

Comment: @mariaMad request.query.limit <= 20 above is perfectly valid, in my case the problem why the access still denied comes from different rules

Comment: ok thanks will see if I have  any rules contradicting with this read

Comment: yes it was some rule contradicting with other rules, thank you although I checked it before asking but I recheked and found it